# Correctly using Avro with Spring, Kafka and Kotlin

Tags: spring, kotlin, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform

With my online application:

- from the browser the user clicks a button which makes a restful call to the application
- the controller receives the restful call and builds a command and either accepts rejects the command
- if valid the Command is fired to a Kafka topic
- application code consumes the commands and fords the Command the appropriate Handler or Handlers
- the handler actions the command on a domain concept
- the domain concept will fire Event(s) to a Kafka topic
- again application consumer with receive the message and forward to interested handlers
- Example Commands

  - `RegisterClientCommand`
  - `PlaceBookingCommand`
  - `CancelBookingCommand`
- Example Events

  - `ClientRegisteredEvent`
  - `BookingPlacedEvent`
  - `BookingCancelledEvent`
- both Commands and Events are of type `DomainMessage`
- each DomainMesage has a `sequence-number`, `createdOn` fields
- I decided to use Avro with schema version support for message exchange
- Spring Kafka Producer:

  - `ProducerFactory<String?, GenericRecord?>`
- Spring Kafka Consumer:

  - `ConsumerFactory<String?, GenericRecord?>`

Point(1) when a Kafka message is sent a GenericRecord is created like so:

```
return GenericRecordBuilder(schema).apply {
    set("first", registerClientCommand.first)
    set("last", registerClientCommand.last)
    set("email", registerClientCommand.email)
    set("mobile", registerClientCommand.mobile)
  }.build()
```

Point(2) when a message is received:
  - a Map is built from the GenericRecord
  - and a concrete RegisterClientCommand is created using the field values in the Map

```
return RegisterClientCommand(
    fields.get("first"),
    fields.get("last"),
    fields.get("email"),
    fields.get("mobile")
  )
```

Does this look correct to you?

I don't like the fact I have to: for each DomainMessage (Commands, Events)

- build the GenericRecord when producing to Kafka as in Point(1) above.
- and build a Map of field values and then build the concrete domain-message
  when consuming from Kafka as in Point(2) above.

Am I using Avro in the right way here?

Answer (score 0):

What about using the Spring Kafka library? This can deal with all sorts of conversion and subscribers.  You need to provide a bean of `RecordMessageConverter`, this bean must implement simple Avro conversion that would convert POJO to Avro and from Avro message to POJO.

Message push can be simplified as well, you need to provide beans `Topic`

Message sending would look like

```
@Service
public class Kafka {
    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<Object, Object> template;
    public void sendClass1(Class1 object) {
        this.template.send("topic1", object);
    }

}
```